I am trying to use .NET Core and Razor to read parameter from GET string
I have Survey.cshtml:
@page 
@model SWAT2022.Views.Home.Index1Model
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
}

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<h2>The time on the server is @DateTime.Now  LAT:@Model.Long  LONG:@Model.Lat </h2>

and the cs Survey.cshtml.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace SWAT2022.Views.Home
{
    public class Index1Model : PageModel
    {
        public string? Lat { get; set; }
        public string? Long { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            Lat = Request.Query["Lat"]; ;
            Long = Request.Query["Long"]; ;
        }
    }
}

I must have a fundamental misunderstanding of RazorPages as I get this error now:


Your screenshot cannot be read because its resolution is too low.

ok added a better picture

@robm add the code and errors as text, not pictures. Pictures can't be copied, googled, compiled or tested

Is this Blazor WebAssembly or Blazor Server? There's no request on the client, where Blazor WebAssembly lives. The client makes multiple requests to the server, it doesn't respond to just one of them. You never read data like this in Blazor anyway. You bind to parameters

@PAGE is not valid Blazor and there are no details on how you test this, param definitions etc.

sorry @HenkHolterman that is my error this is a "Razor page - Empty"  does that make more sense

Try Injecting the NavigationManager service to get access to the query string parameters.
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<h2>The time on the server is @DateTime.Now</h2>
<h2>LAT: @latitude LONG: @longitude</h2>

@code {
    private string latitude;
    private string longitude;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var uri = Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri(Navigation.Uri);
        var queryParameters = Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query);

    if (queryParameters.TryGetValue("lat", out var lat))
    {
        latitude = lat;
    }

    if (queryParameters.TryGetValue("long", out var lon))
    {
        longitude = lon;
    }
  }
 }


Or just bind to them using the correct attributes. NavigationManager isn't meant for reading URI parameters

@PanagiotisKanavos: I must disagree. NavigationManager was introduced earlier than SupplyParameterFromQuery and it was the only way. Besides SupplyParameterFromQuery has very nasty bug, which forced me to use NavigationManager anyway

Edit:
Cause your application is Razor Pages, I have updated my solution as below:
Test.cshtml:
@page
@model ReadParameter.Pages.TestModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";
}

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<h2>The time on the server is @DateTime.Now  LAT:@Model.Lat  LONG:@Model.Long </h2>

Test.cshtml.cs:
public class TestModel : PageModel
{
    public string? Lat {  get; set; }
    public string? Long { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Lat = Request.Query["Lat"]; ;
        Long = Request.Query["Long"]; ;
    }
}

result:



Orginal answer:
To read the GET string parameters, you can use the [SupplyParameterFromQuery] attribute to specify that a component parameter comes from the query string.
You can find detailed usage instructions at this link：https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-8.0#query-strings
1. Here's the code that can work on both Blazor Web and Blazor WebAssembly App:
@page "/Test"
<h3>Test</h3>

<h1>Test Read Query Parameter</h1>
<h2>The time on the server is @DateTime.Now</h2>
<h2>LAT: @Lat LONG: @Long</h2>

@code {
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
    public string? Lat { get; set; }
    [SupplyParameterFromQuery]
    public string? Long { get; set; }
}

My Test Result:

2. Here's the code that can work on Blazor Server:
@page "/Test/{Lat}/{Long}"
<h3>Test</h3>

<h1>Test Read Query Parameter</h1>
<h2>The time on the server is @DateTime.Now</h2>
<h2>LAT: @Lat LONG: @Long</h2>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? Lat { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string? Long { get; set; }
}

or
@page "/Test2"

@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<h3>Test</h3>

<h1>Test Read Query Parameter</h1>
<h2>The time on the server is @DateTime.Now</h2>
<h2>LAT: @Lat LONG: @Long</h2>

@code {
    public string? Lat { get; set; }

    public string? Long { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var uri = Navigation.ToAbsoluteUri(Navigation.Uri);
        var queryParameters = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);

        if (queryParameters.HasKeys())
        {
            if (queryParameters.AllKeys.Contains("Lat"))
            {
                Lat = queryParameters["Lat"];
            }

            if (queryParameters.AllKeys.Contains("Long"))
            {
                Long = queryParameters["Long"];
            }
        }
    }
}


The first sentence in incorrect. Blazor Server Side RUNS ON SERVER and uses websockets to communicate with browser. Blazor WebAssembly runs on client and doesn't use websockects

Indeed, the entire first paragraph is wrong and ruins an otherwise good answer. Using SupplyParameterFromQuery is better than trying to read the query parameters

@Liero, thanks for recommend me about that.

@Panagiotis Kanavos, thanks for recommend me about that.

The first example works on server too. Second does not use querystring. The third works on WebAssembly too

I am an idiat it is a Razor page empty I added

Hello, @robm, thanks for your coming back and providing more information, I have updated my reply, hope it can help you.

I get an error now to ReadParameter now   Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Details
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'ReadParameter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) SWAT2022 C:\Users\RobMe\source\repos\SWAT2022\SWAT2022\Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Razor.Compiler.SourceGenerators\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.SourceGenerators.RazorSourceGenerator\Views_Home_Survey_cshtml.g.cs 92 Active

@robm，did you use this line @model ReadParameter.Pages.TestModel in your code? It is because the ReadParameter is the name of my project, and my Test.cshtml.cs is under the folder Pages. So, you should change it to your PageModel file path.

@YumiaoKong I updated the original showing that model update but now get a NullException

This is definitely a rather incidental issue. Please try deleting these two files, then add a new Razor page and run the application again to see if the error persists.
